# How to restrict google auto completion to search only a few neibourghoods in a city?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

How to restrict google places auto-completion API searching area to a specific area? For example, I just want to search for the result in Melbourne CBD area. Is there any way to limit to this area?

Comment: You can define, lat long bound for this

Answer (score 2):

Use **FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest** object like this with **bounds** like below,

```
RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596));

FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = 
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
// Call either setLocationBias() OR setLocationRestriction().
 .setLocationBias(bounds)
 //.setLocationRestriction(bounds)
 .setCountry("au")
 .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.REGIONS)
 .build();
```